# How to convert map values using Spark built-in functions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple dataset with schema:

```
root
 |-- columns: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- a: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: float (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- d: double (nullable = true)
           |-- ... 
           |-- ...
```

Example:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|columns                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|[k0 -> [,,,, 2,], k1 -> [,,,, AB,], k2 -> [,,M,,,] |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to transform my dataset into a new dataset with schema:

```
root
 |-- columns: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string
```

Transformation rules:

1. Struct size is undefined.
2. Get 1st not empty element from value struct (as a string).

Output Example:

```
+----------------------------+
|columns                     |
+----------------------------+
|[k0 -> 2, k1 -> AB, k2 -> M |
+----------------------------+
```

Here is my UDF solution

```
val my_udf: UserDefinedFunction = udf((m: Map[String, Row]) => m.map { case (k, v) => (k, v.toSeq.find(_ != null).map(_.toString)) })

df.select(my_udf(col("columns")))
```

Is it possible to rewrite it using Spark built-in functions?

Something like this:

```
df.withColumn("data", expr("transform(fields.items(), (k, v) -> (k, get-1st-not-null-element-from-v)"))
```

Here is another try (Spark 3.0+):

```
df.select(map_entries(col("fields")).as("array"))
.select(
  expr(
    "transform(array, (e, _) -> " +
      "struct(cast(e.key as string), coalesce(e.value.a, e.value.b, e.value.c, e.value.d, ...)))"
    ).as("entries")
  )
.select(map_from_entries(col("entries")))
```

Comment: If you're using Spark 2.4+, then have you considered a higher-order function - `transform()` passed inside `selectExpr()`?

Comment: I don;t think there is a map (k, v) iteration available in Spark. UDF seems to be the only way

Comment: @undying_odyssey Yes, I added 'transform' example to the post. However it uses Spark 3.0+ features. I'd rather stay with Spark 2.4.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#transform) + [aggregate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#aggregate) (assumed the column name is `col1`):

```
df.selectExpr("""
  aggregate(
    transform(map_keys(col1), x -> map(x, coalesce(col1[x].a,col1[x].b,col1[x].c,col1[x].d))), 
    /* zero_value: use an empty map() */
    map(), 
    /* merge: do map_concat() */
    (acc,y) -> map_concat(acc, y)
  )  as col1
""").show()
```

**Where:**

- Use *transform()* function to iterate through the array from `map_keys`, convert each item `x` into a map with `x` as key and set the value to the first non-null value from the StructType field using `coalesce(col1[x].a,col1[x].b,col1[x].c,col1[x].d)`. This will result into an array of maps.
- use *aggregate()* function to merge the above array of maps into a MapType column.

For spark 3.0+, use [transform_values](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/api/sql/index.html#transform_values):

```
df.selectExpr("transform_values(col1, (k,v) -> coalesce(v.a, v.b, v.c, v.d)) as col1").show()
```

Comment: The OP specified that the struct size is undefined. Therefore, you have to look at the dataframe's schema to find the struct field names. Also, if you are using Spark 3.0, use the DSL for higher-order functions: easier than code generating SQL.